# returning another page's variables using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX to try and return list items. The list items are stored on another page as a var. The var is called WPQListData. This var is viewable in the page source.

```
var WPQ2ListData = { "Row" : 
[{
"ID": "1",
"PermMask": "0x7fffffffffffffff",
"FSObjType": "0",
"Title": "test",
"FileLeafRef": "1_.000",
"Created_x0020_Date.ifnew": "",
"FileRef": "\u002fsites\u002fResilient\u002fLists\u002fNewsSliderList\u002f1_.000",
"File_x0020_Type": "",
"File_x0020_Type.mapapp": "",
"HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapcon": "",
"HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapico": "icgen.gif",
"ContentTypeId": "0x0100B87D22D691BA4B419255256292F918AA00B2962D0F358E9442AFF496C5DFF6AB1F",
"Body1": "test"
}
```

Id like to get this variable using AJAX. I'm currently trying the following:

```
$.ajax({
        url: ctx.HttpRoot+"/Lists/NewsSliderList/AllItems.aspx",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            var dataDom = $(data);
            var stripped_data = $(dataDom).find("WPQ2ListData");
        },
        error: function () {
            // your error logic
            alert("AJAX failed");
        }
    })
```

Is it possible to get Vars via AJAX, and if so then what am i doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: I guess anything is possible, but what you're doing is not really how ajax works, it's get the source from that other file, and parsing the HTML you can use find() to find an element, not a javascript variable, that would require some more advanced parsing, assuming it's not a cross domain request, which would be stopped by the same origin policy

Comment: Pages should not be used as a source for data.

Comment: the page already has data returned. I want to check the list to see if anything has been added since the last reload, then update the results if they have